# What type of partition table and file system is required to make a live usb?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, live-usb

I see a bunch of stuff on using usb-creator to make a live usb for ubuntu which is great.

What I don't see is what type of partition table and file system is required on the USB itself.  Does it have to be fat32?

Please provide partition table ID, and file system type as well as commands:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
# Make bootable and chose ID = c (W95 fat32 (lba) )
sudo mkfs.vfat -n 'ubuntu' /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 4):

As other people have already said, if you use the Ubuntu's "Startup Disk Creator" and then check the filesystem type it turns out to be FAT32. But what was not said is that *there is no need to format* a USB disk before creating the installation/boot disk. The reason is that you are probably using the ISO image of the installation disk. The ISO image contains a complete filesystem inside (an ISO9660 file system) and is copied byte-by-byte to the USB stick.

So it does not matter what type of filesystem you create before copying ISO image, since it will be replaced by the filesystem of ISO image.

P.S. and of course there is no need to use the Ubuntu's "Startup Disk Creator" since good old `dd` command will do the same job much faster

```
$ sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=2048
```

Note that you have to give the `dd` command the path to the drive `/dev/sbX` (i.e. USB stick), *not* the path to a particular partition `/dev/sdX1`, `/dev/sdX2` or whatever.

Also note that setting blocksize `bs=2048` will make the copying process much faster.

Comment: And so, IT means that the ISO file already contains the partition table and it must Not BE (re-)created manually before dd'ing.

Comment: This does not comment which partition table it should be. Likely `mbr`, but it could also be `gpt` (and there are others, e.g. `loop`, which are unlike to be used).

Answer (score 2):

My USB is formatted fat32.  If you use "Start-up Disk Creator", you should not have any problems with a fat32 formatted USB stick.  Just give it the ISO you want copied and it will do the rest for you.

After creating my 14.04LTS bootable USB for installation, Disk Utility shows format is W95 Fat32 Bootable.  Done automatically by Startup Disk Creator, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To make live USB you can put USB format to fat32 or ntfs or ext4 after installing Ubuntu to usb it turns to bootable. Coming to partition table you don't need any partition table you can install on whole USB or if you want you can create a partition table and set one partition space enough for ubuntu live usb and format to any above three. You can select your partition drive at unetbootin usb options.

Personally i don't prefer ntfs because it will be slow it wont be like hard disk. I recommend to use fat32.

If you create a partition table create only one live usb partition don't use two at a time only the second will work.

I hope this helps